# jQuery draggable plugin i want to update px to mm on drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to know if there is any trick or hack to j-query Drag-able plugin,
so that **on-drag** event i want to update left and top position with unit **mm** not **PX** 
for example

```
<div id="text" style="position:relative;top:22px;left:100px;">sample text</div>
```

should change to

```
<div id="text" style="position:relative;top:22mm;left:100mm;">sample text</div>
```

or how can i make a custom j-query plugin??to get this work